# Setting up and accessing array of void pointers

Tags: c, pointers

In a block of memory, treatead as two segments, A and B,
i set up pointers in segment A such that values from
segment B can be viewed as matrices and accessed by indices:

```
float **matrix = ( ( void ** ) view->data[ i ] )[ j ];
```

After allocating memory and assigning the pointers i then set all the
values for a specific matrix.
However, when trying to print individual values of that matrix,
the program seg-faults due to an invalid read.
If i dont't call the set_weights function, values are printed
fine ( and valgrind reports no leaks ). So i assume that trying
to set values has an unwanted side effect of messing up pointers.

I would like to understand if the error is in the pointer assignments
or on access.
Pease have a look and help me.

Regards,
Alfred

[ OS: x86_64 debian linux, gcc 4.2.9 ]

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { Weight, Delta, Max };

typedef struct {
    void **data;
} View;

void matrix_2D_print( int x, int y, float **values ) {
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < x; ++i ) {
        for( j = 0; j < y; ++j ) {
            printf( "\t\t%f", values[ i ][ j ] ); // Invalid read
            if( j < ( y - 1 ) ) {
                printf( ", " );
            }
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

void set_weights( int layers, int x, int y, View *view ) {
    int i, j, l;
    void **view_ptr = view->data[ Weight ];

    for( l = 0; l < layers; ++l ) {
        float **m2_data = view_ptr[ l ];

        for( i = 0; i < x; ++i ) {
            for( j = 0; j < y; ++j ) {
                m2_data[ i ][ j ] = 0.27f;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    int i, l, m;
    int x = 3;
    int y = 2;
    int layers = 2;
    size_t step_view = Max * sizeof( void ** );
    size_t len_step_view = x * sizeof( void ** );
    size_t len_segment_A = step_view + x * layers * Max * sizeof( void ** );
    size_t len_segment_B = x * y * layers * Max * sizeof( float );
    char *storage = calloc( 1, len_segment_A + len_segment_B );
    float *segment_b = ( float * )( storage + len_segment_A );
    View view;
    view.data = ( void ** ) storage;

    for( m = 0; m < Max; ++m ) {
        void **segment_a = ( void ** )( storage + step_view );
        view.data[ m ] = segment_a;

        for( l = 0; l < layers; ++l ) {
            segment_a[ l ] = segment_b;
            void **cur = segment_a[ l ];

            for( i = 0; i < x; ++i ) {
                cur[ i ] = segment_b;
                segment_b += y;
            }
            step_view += len_step_view;
        }
    }
    assert( len_segment_A == step_view );
    set_weights( layers, x, y, &view );

    void **view_ptr = view.data[ Weight ];
    printf( "\tLayer: %d\n", 0 );
    matrix_2D_print( x, y, view_ptr[ 0 ] );

    free( storage );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accesing the zero-th element, am i wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing all this pointer arithmetic instead of just declaring a `struct`? It's incredibly confusing to keep track of all the pointers.

Comment: The reason i am doing this is because i want to allocate the total memory my program needs at once and prior to setting the dimensions and values of the respective matrices. So even if i used structs somehow, i would end up having to bend some pointers. But maybe i am adding complication to where there is none, would you please describe the layout of a struct as you proposed?

Comment: As I'm unable to understand this code on a second sight (and too lazy to completely analyze it): You just want a matrix of `float`s with runtime-determined dimensions, is this correct?

Comment: It would be simpler to `malloc` each array separately, and put pointers to each array into the `view` structure.

Comment: I want to improve my network which right now uses dynamic allocation. This is simpliy not feasible for long running tests. So i will have: for each layer of the network an array of matrices (e.g. for weights and deltas, etc.).